# How can I integrate $\frac{1}{z-1}$ with $z$ as a complex number, without Cauchy's integral formula?

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove that when I integrate $\dfrac{1}{z-a} =2 πi$ without using Cauchy's Integration Formula. We are integrating along a circle centered at zero. And a < r where r is the radius of the curve gamma upon which we are integrating.

Have worked on it for a while and have no idea. I tried defining a new curve around$ a$ and thought maybe doing some adding or subtracting from the integration over the larger curve would help -- but didn't get anywhere with it.

Comment: Your brief mention of a gamma curve is… too brief.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's 2am and I've been working on homework for roughly 10 hours. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps can easily be justified using uniform convergence:

$\int_C \frac 1 {z-a} dz= \int_C \frac  1 z \frac  1 {1-\frac  a  z} dz= \int_C \frac  1 z \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (\frac  a z)^{n}dz= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_C \frac {a^{n}} {z^{n+1}} dz$. Now all the terms except the first one are $0$ and the first one is $2\pi i$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could just integrate by hand, with the principal branch of log.  $\oint_C1/(z-a)\DeclareMathOperator{\d}{d}\d z=\int_0^{2\pi}ire^{it}/(re^{it}-a)\d t=[\log (re^{it}-a)]_0^{2\pi}=2\pi i$.

Or you can use the residue theorem.  The residue is clearly $1$.

Comment: Thank you. We have not been taught residue theorem or logs in the complex plane yet. It seems this question is supposed to lead up to all that.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\frac{dre^{i\theta}}{re^{i\theta}-a}=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\frac{(re^{-i\theta}-\bar a)\,dre^{i\theta}}{r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)+|a|^2}=i\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\frac{(r^2-r\bar ae^{i\theta})d\theta}{r^2-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)+|a|^2}$$ where $\phi$ is the argument of $a$.

We can ignore $\phi$ as the integral is over a full period, and decompose the integrand in three terms,

$$\frac a{\cos(\theta)+p}, \frac{b\cos(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)+p}, \frac{c\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta)+p}, $$ with some constant coefficients. As the contour surrounds $a$, we have $p>1$. By antisymmetry, the third term brings no contribution and the useful terms can be rewritten as

$$a,\frac b{\cos(\theta)+p}.$$